# change the body class for a div and restore default when div changes

Tags: html

I want to change the class of the `body` for a particular `div` and restore the default when the `div` changes.

eg:             `<div id='test'></div>` #class of the body as new

```
  `<div id ='test2'> </div>` #class of the body as default
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have control on when the div changes?

Comment: no I have no control. @Reddy

Comment: damn!!! this is indeed a good question.

Comment: What is the body of a div? What do you mean by "when the div changes.". Changes how?

Comment: not body of the div! body of the whole page.

Comment: @PeeHaa he has a div and if the div id changes he has to change the body element class attribute.

Comment: some data will be in div1 and other in div2. When div1 is displayed the whole body of the page must change. and when div2 is displayed the body of the page must be default.

Comment: @PeeHaa Reddy is right.

Comment: @sharon only possiblity will be to use jquery and check the div id's for every xxx seconds and if there is a change then we can change the body class accordingly..

Comment: @Reddy an example can be helpful to me.

Comment: @sharon added my answer.. let me know if it helps

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)?

Answer (score 0):

> This may not be the efficient way. But since you asked for a example I
>   am providing one.

There are few tools available for this kind of a job like **[Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)** and its browser  [**Compatibality**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver)

But if you want a dirty work around then below is my sample.

You can use Jquery to Check the div id for every x seconds and set the body class accordingly. Here is a sample code.

```js
//demo purpose, this script toggles the div id to be test and test2 for each click.
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var currID = $('.demo').attr('id');
  if (currID === "test") {
    $('.demo').attr('id', "test2");
  } else {
    $('.demo').attr('id', "test");
  }
});


//below is the actual logic, this will change the body class according to div id
setInterval(function() {
  var currID = $('.demo').attr('id');
  if (currID === "test") {
    $('body').removeClass('default').addClass('new');
  } else {
    $('body').removeClass('new').addClass('default');
  }
}, 100); // run this interval every 100 miliseconds, you can set it to your preference
```

```css
.new {
  background-color: green;
}
.default {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="new" style="height:200px;">
  <div id="test" class="demo"></div>
  <button>Toggle Div's Id</button>
</body>
```